# Authorization using Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc

#### 1. Backstory

I recently starting programming and I found out that Entity Framework works perfect for my small-sized applications due its simplicity.

I've made my custom authorize attribute for MVC controllers and controller methods to check if the current user has a certain role (which is an enum type in my case).

The following code represents my authorize attribute:

```
public class HasRoleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private Role _role;

    public HasRoleAttribute(Role role)
    {
        this._role = role;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var context = new FactoryManagementContext();

        var userName = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(item => item.UserName == userName);      

        var hasRole = user.Role == _role;

        if (user == null || !hasRole)
        {
            // If this user does not have the
            // required permission then redirect to login page
            var url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
            var loginUrl = url.Content("/Account/Login");
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, true);
        }
    }
}

public enum Role 
{
    Engineer,
    Manager,
    Admin
}
```

#### 2. Question

It works as a charm, but I have only one question: is it necessary to initialize the database context every single time when authorizing a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not instanciate a new DbContext each time your code go throw your ActionFilter. 
 What you should do is to use [**dependency injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and to define an execution scope.

Because you are using .net Framework and not .net core, I advise you to look into DI providers such as [Autofac](https://autofac.org/) or [Ninject](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html).

I advise you to look into [why to use DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Advantages) and think about what execution scope you need (probably `perScope()` in your case).

Hope it helps.